# Best method of converting Pandas dataframe into list of dictionaries for each column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I've got a pandas dataframe which does not have a known size/shape. I need to convert this dataframe into a list of dictionaries with the layout:

```
[
{"heading": column1name, "values":[list of column 1 values]},
{"heading": column2name, "values":[list of column 2 values]},
...and so on
]
```

I am currently doing this by using a for loop to iterate over each column and appending a dictionary to the list:

```
def sendHeadingsAndValues():
    columns = list(USER_DATA.columns.values)
    dd_columnList = []
    
    for column in columns:
        dd_columnList.append({"heading": column, "values": USER_DATA[column].to_list()})
    
    return dd_columnList
```

This is fairly inefficient for large dataframes with multiple columns so I'm wondering if there's a quicker method of doing this?

I'd appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: What is inefficient about this?

Comment: I'm not sure to be completely honest. I've read that it's generally a bad idea to iterate over rows/columns when using Pandas as there's usually a quicker "vectorized" way of doing things though idk if that applies here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pandas.DataFrame.to_dict together with a list comprehension.See below:

```
import pandas as pd

d=df.to_dict('list')

res=[{'heading':i, 'values':k} for i, k in d.items()]
```

Example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,20,30,40], 'b':[100,200,300,400]})

>>>print(df)
    a    b
0  10  100
1  20  200
2  30  300
3  40  400

d=df.to_dict('list')
    
res=[{'heading':i, 'values':k} for i, k in d.items()]

>>> print(res)

[{'heading': 'a', 'values': [10, 20, 30, 40]}, {'heading': 'b', 'values': [100, 200, 300, 400]}]
```